# Deepin: shortcut to move window to other monitor

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, multi-monitor, manjaro, deepin

I use manjaro deepin and even thou I love this beautiful desktop environment I really miss a keyboard shortcut that let me move a window from one monitor to the other (2 monitors).

I already tried the next script I used on XFCE:

```
yaourt -S --noconfirm xorg-xprop xorg-xwininfo xorg-xrandr wmctrl
git clone https://github.com/calandoa/movescreen.git
sudo mv movescreen/movescreen.py /usr/bin
rm -rf movescreen//usr/local/bin/movescreen.py
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/bin/movescreen.py
```

**Menu | All settings | Keyboard | Application shortcuts | Add**

`/usr/local/bin/movescreen.py left`     **Ctrl+Super+Left**

`/usr/local/bin/movescreen.py right`    **Ctrl+Super+Right**

but it didn't work. I tryed adding this shortcut using deepin Control Center, not the XFCE way.

How can I add a command to move a window to left/right monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
diff --git a/movescreen.py b/movescreen.py
index b6bd4ad..99b7a7c 100755
--- a/movescreen.py
+++ b/movescreen.py
@@ -23,7 +23,7 @@ if 2 < len(sys.argv):
 else:
        # Get focused window
        out = subprocess.check_output(['xprop', '-root', '_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW']).decode('ascii', 'ignore')
-       id = re.search("window id # (0x[0-9a-f]+),", out).group(1)
+       id = re.search('window id # (0x[0-9a-f]+)', out).group(1)


 # Get screens information
```

Comment: Although if I run this script from the terminal it works, when I add it to Deepin Shortcut it doesn't :-|

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier  (and probably also better) way to this using `gsettings`.

> I suggest using the `dconf-editor` to modify `gsettings`. It is also possible to do the following from the command line directly via the `gsettings` command, but the visual editor is much simpler.

The following is the set up for Fedora, tested on Fedora 30:

1) Get the `dconf-editor`:

```
sudo dnf install -y dconf-editor
```

2) Open up the editor and look up the path to the keybindings

From the gnome terminal:

```
dconf-editor
```

[image]

3) Open up the settings and set the shortcuts as described in the picture above (or use your own shortcuts)

And you're all set

Answer (score 0):

In the `dconf-editor`, setting the `move-to-monitor-left` and `-right` did not work for me. But `move-to-side-e` and `-w` works.

Answer (score 0):

On manjaro this is how I do it:

system settings -> shortcuts -> global shortcuts

then search for `window to next screen`

[image]

In my case I have used a custom shortcut `Meta + N`