# What is the keyboard shortcut to move application window from one monitor to another

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, deepin

I was looking forward to move an application window from one monitor to another with a keyboard shortcut on Deepin system. I tried a couple of different ways.

1. `dconf-editor` as described in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/517192
2. Tried the following commands

   ```
   gsettings set com.deepin.wrap.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-monitor-left '["<Super><Shift>Left"]'


   gsettings set com.deepin.wrap.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-monitor-right '["Super><Shift>Right"]'
   ```

Didn't really work. Can anyone please help?

Comment: What does “didn’t really work” mean?  What exactly happened?

Comment: From dconf-editor clearly it should've worked. But neither this nor the gsettings commands works. When I ran the command it doesn't show any error. But doesn't achieve the desired output also.